# What should the CSV file format look like for correct parsing with pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

I get an error parsing my `CSV` file that I want to convert to `XLSX`. The part of the file it complains about looks like this:

```
Number,2000-00-00 
,,System,,,,,,,,,,,,System,  
,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,
Settings, Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,
System,"dist, dist, dist, dist",0,104,21,65,0,128,5,29,0,62,0,1,0,11993,26,56,0,1321,14,18,0,63,0,0, 
 
Number,2000-00-00 
,,System,,,,,,,,,,,,System,  
,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,,,,Type,
Settings, Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,Sample,
System,"dist, dist, dist, dist",0,1141,29,71,0,121,3,15,0,62,0,0,0,14034,22,47,0,84,1,10,0,80,0,0,

Total,,0,8436,13,62,0,839,24,163,0,451,0,2,0,97906,235,434,0,846,38,10,0,462,0,2, 
Total 2,,,,,841,,,,8556,,,,453,,,,985,,,,869,,,,46 
Total 3 ,,,,,,,,,,,,,350,,,,,,,,,,,,1078 
Full,,2898
```

Example of error:

```
converter         | Skipping line 3: expected 16 fields, saw 24
converter         | Skipping line 4: expected 16 fields, saw 27
converter         | Skipping line 5: expected 16 fields, saw 27
```

[Screenshot](https://sun9-45.userapi.com/impg/x_lBH1QvPOxE7RcLSQpUxOZ37I71aZqE0hJNfQ/T7VwhLsp6OE.jpg?size=1566x296&quality=95&sign=7480bc958a22b1d79a62cf0768802798&type=album)

So I understand it's about a lot of delimiters, which are needed to form empty fields. Although pandas complains about the parsing error, the file itself looks correct when opened. Is it really about consecutive delimiters? If so, why does the file itself look correct? If not, what could be the problem?

Comment: For best results - you should aim to have the same number of delimiters in each row.

Comment: How many delimiters do you think each of your input lines has?  If they are different, Pandas won't read it.